# sys.argv 1 list index out of range

Tags: python, argv

I'm trying to run this code properly and pass the arguments but I get this error

```
sys.argv 1 list index out of range
```

I understand that it requires the arguments to be passed correctly on the command line

How do I pass the arguments correctly?

Thanks

```
import sys
import os
import re
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import pos_tag


def clean(path, filename):

# print("Cleaning "+path)

filename = CLEANED_DATA + filename.strip()
WRITE_HANDLER = open(filename, 'w')
tweets = dict()
for line in open('path', 'r'):
    line = re.sub(r'[.,"!]+', '', line, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # removes the characters specified
    line = re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+', '', line, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # removes RT
    line = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', line,
                  flags=re.MULTILINE)  # remove link
    line = re.sub(r'[:]+', '', line, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    line = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, line)  # filter non-ascii characters

    new_line = ''
    for i in line.split():  # remove @ and #words, punctuataion
        if not i.startswith('@') and not i.startswith('#') and i \
            not in string.punctuation:
            new_line += i + ' '
    line = new_line

    # # Do sentence correction

    if new_line in tweets:
        continue
    else:
        tweets[new_line] = 1
    if len(new_line.strip()) > 0:
        WRITE_HANDLER.write(new_line + '''

''')
    return filename


DATA_FOLDER = sys.argv[1]
CLEANED_DATA = sys.argv[2]
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(DATA_FOLDER):  # gets all the files from 
subfolders recrsively
   for name in files:
       absolute_path = os.path.join(root, name)
       if os.path.isfile(absolute_path) and name != '.DS_Store':
           filename = clean(absolute_path, name)

        # preprocess(filename, name) -- Call seperate tag code for this task
```

Comment: what command are you using?

Comment: Separate them from the program name with spaces, like `python program.py arg1 arg2`

Comment: python clean.py tweets.txt cleantweets.txt

Comment: my path is defined as /Users/Silas/Desktop/tweets.txt

Comment: I run the command  
python clean.py tweets.txt cleantweets.txt  but it doesn't output anything. I'm pointing to the file that needs to be read in and cleaned and the output file name

Comment: Can you provide me with an example of how you would run this code from the command line. Defining the directory to read the tweets from and where it would be saved to, in this case CLEANED_DATA

Answer (score 0):

You pass system arguments when you run the code in your terminal

```
python script.py {arg1} ... {argN}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` in Python is a list, initialized by the `sys` module which contains a *copy* of the process' "argument vector" (thus the name).

This "argument vector" is prepared for every process by the operating system.  Unix, MS Windows™ and almost every other general purpose operating system prepares the argument vector for every process.  Most of these are built on the assumption that a user command line shell will be used to enter commands (including names of programs, such as those you're writing) along with any arguments to be passed to those programs.

If you look at the Unix/Linux and similar system level APIs and shell implementations you'll find that the shell parses a command line, expands various variables and "glob" (filename wildcard) patterns into matching lists of files and splits the text into a "vector" (in C that's a sequence of NUL terminated strings terminated by another NUL character).  This is passed (along with the full path to the command/executable filename) to the *execve()* system call (usually after some variant of the *fork()* system call).  That's how programs are run (and where new processes come from).

Because *sys.argv* is merely a copy of the process' argument vector, and it's implemented as a simple Python list, you can modify it as you would with any other list.  Just *.append()* some arguments (list of strings) unto it, or use a slice assignment `sys.argv[1:] = ['arg1', 'arg2', ...]` if you want to call some function that uses it.

Comment: I understand that, what I mean is specifically how should I pass my arguments on the command line. eg. python clean.py cleantweets.txt?  or python clean.py tweets.txt cleantweets.txt

Comment: I do specify the path as /Users/Silas/Desktop/tweets.txt